# pass value from adapter to another activity through interface

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, interface, adapter

please dont mark my question as duplicate as none of the solutions wotked for me

i was trying to pass value from adapter to another activity through interface.......

the error shows at this evrytime :---   `data clickedItem = mdata.get(position);`

giving as

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

following is my code :-------------------
Adapter :---

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> {
Context mContext;
 List<data> mExampleList;
 OnItemClickListener mListener;
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
public ExampleAdapter(Context context,List<data> exampleList) {
    mContext = context;
    mExampleList = exampleList;
}
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.employeelist, parent, false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh = new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    return evh;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    data currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

    Picasso.get().load(currentItem.getAvatar()).into(holder.mimageView);

    holder.mtextview1.setText(String.format("%s %s", currentItem.getFirst_name(), currentItem.getLast_name()));
    holder.mtextveiew2.setText(currentItem.getEmail());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mListener.onItemClick(position);

        }
    });

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExampleList.size();
}
public class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView mimageView;
    public TextView mtextview1;
    public TextView mtextveiew2;
    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mimageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mtextview1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        mtextveiew2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    }
}
```

}

Another activity:--

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.tvEmail);
    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String emailadd = intent.getStringExtra("email");
    textView.setText(emailadd);

}
```

}

Sample pojo :--

```
public class SampleResponse {
@SerializedName("page")
@Expose
private String page;
@SerializedName("per_page")
@Expose
private String per_page;
@SerializedName("total")
@Expose
private String total;
@SerializedName("total_pages")
@Expose
private String total_pages;
@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private List<data> dataArray = null;

public String getPage() {
    return page;
}

public void setPage(String page) {
    this.page = page;
}

public String getPer_page() {
    return per_page;
}

public void setPer_page(String per_page) {
    this.per_page = per_page;
}

public String getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(String total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public String getTotal_pages() {
    return total_pages;
}

public void setTotal_pages(String total_pages) {
    this.total_pages = total_pages;
}

public List<data> getDataArray() {
    return dataArray;
}

public void setDataArray(List<data> dataArray) {
    this.dataArray = dataArray;
}
```

}

data pojo:--

```
public class data {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("first_name")
@Expose
private String first_name;
@SerializedName("last_name")
@Expose
private String last_name;
@SerializedName("email")
@Expose
private String email;
@SerializedName("avatar")
@Expose
private String avatar;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}
```

}

main activity:--

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ExampleAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
 RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
 ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
 RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
 List<data> mdata;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    
    jsonparse();
}

private void jsonparse() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://reqres.in/api/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    EmployeeAPI request = retrofit.create(EmployeeAPI.class);
    Call<SampleResponse> call1 = request.getJson(10);
    call1.enqueue(new Callback<SampleResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SampleResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<SampleResponse> response) {

            List<data> exampleList = response.body().getDataArray();
            mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this,exampleList);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SampleResponse> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, Details.class);
    data clickedItem = mdata.get(position);
    detailIntent.putExtra("email", clickedItem.getEmail());
    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```

Comment: where are you using `example adapter`?

Comment: where are you making a new instance of `ExampleAdapter` ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody did you get where am i going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: where are you assigning a value to `List<data> mdata;` in main activity ?

Comment: @IRONMAN I suspect that your response is having error `List<data> exampleList = response.body().getDataArray();` (in your activity) which is why your adapter crashes. check if your list contains null values or not.

Comment: @JeelVankhede OP doesn't seem to ever be assigning a value to `List<data> mdata;` then later tries to access it when the callback triggers in main activity, or am i wrong ?

Comment: @JeelVankhede i debug `List<data> exampleList = response.body().getDataArray(); ` got--->`Response{protocol=h2, code=200, message=, url=https:/xxxxxxxpi/users?per_page=10}

Comment: @IRONMAN you haven't answered my question : `where are you assigning a value to List<data> mdata; in main activity ?`

Comment: @a_local_nobody Yes that is correct. `mdata` is null is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with the `NullPointerException` is due to your variable `List<data> mdata;` on the activity.

The reason it is crashing is because you've declared variable `List<data> mdata;` but never assigned value to it, thus it eventually crash due to 'null pointer' because there's no value to read from that variable.

I would suggest following modification on your activity to fix your issue temporarily but still permanent fix would be refactor on `OnItemClickListener`.

**Temporary fix:**

On your `jsonparse()` method, you'll need to assign value to `mdata` and then use it afterwards like below code snippet:

```
mdata = response.body().getDataArray(); // remove local variable from here and assign value directly to mdata
mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(MainActivity.this, mdata); // instead of local variable exampleList, you now pass mdata
```

This will fix your issue temporarily

**Permanent fix:**

To fix this properly, I would suggest following refactor *(I recommend this approach because it would be less error prone and doesn't require you to have local variable on activity)*.

Instead of passing position from adapter to activity, you should instead pass variable directly via method, so that you don't end up storing list locally.

Modified interface:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(data selectedData);
}
```

& During onClick on adapter item, use it like this: `mListener.onItemClick(mExampleList.get(position));`

This also changes your code on activity where you override method:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(data selectedData) {
    Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, Details.class);
    detailIntent.putExtra("email", selectedData.getEmail());
    startActivity(detailIntent);
}
```